# How can I make path of the text will be displayed in Yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to print a text in an external file as a message. The source will be YML. The path of the text will be displayed in YML.

```java
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages.yaml"); //how will this happen
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

in YML file

```yml
resource_locations: file:///C:/messages/
```

File `message.txt`

```
txt.err.100 = succes
txt.err.999 = failure
```

Answer (score 0):

If its `application.yml` file which is used for spring configuration. You can read its content in Java file using `@Value` annotation

```java
@Value("${externalFile.path}")
String filePath;
```

Then you can use `resourceLoader` to get the content of this file

```java
ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("file:filePath/fileName.txt");
```